# root.findall('foo') and root.iter('foo') not returning any results

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I have a large xml representation of a swedish dictionary. 
I am looking for all the nouns, which are labelled as 'subst.' in the file.

Here is a section of the file which represents one entry (Article) for the word 'a':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"  href="transform_lexin.xsl"?>
<Dictionary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="lexinAA.xsd">
  <Article ID="1000002" Sortkey="a">
    <Lemma Value="a" Variant="" Type="subst." ID="1000002" LemmaID="1" VariantID="3, 4" Rank="350">
      <Phonetic File="a.swf">a:</Phonetic>
      <Inflection Form="best.f.sing.">a:et</Inflection>
      <Inflection Form="obest.f.pl.">a:n</Inflection>
      <Inflection Form="best.f.pl.">a:na</Inflection>
      <Index Value="a" />
      <Index Value="a:et" />
      <Index Value="a:n" />
      <Index Value="a:na" />
      <Index Value="as" />
      <Index Value="a:ets" />
      <Index Value="a:ns" />
      <Index Value="a:nas" />
      <Lexeme ID="1" Lexemeno="1" LexemeID="1000006" VariantID="3">
        <Definition>första bokstaven i alfabetet</Definition>
        <Idiom ID="1000008" OldID="2">a och o<Definition ID="1000009">det viktigaste</Definition></Idiom>
        <Idiom ID="1000010" OldID="1">har man sagt a får man också säga b<Definition ID="1000011">har man börjat får man fortsätta</Definition></Idiom>
      </Lexeme>
      <Lexeme ID="2" Lexemeno="2" LexemeID="1000013" VariantID="4">
        <Definition>sjätte tonen i C-durskalan</Definition>
        <Compound OldID="" ID="2000667">a-moll</Compound>
        <Compound OldID="" ID="2000668">A-dur</Compound>
        <Index Value="a-moll" />
        <Index Value="a-molls" />
        <Index Value="a moll" />
        <Index Value="a molls" />
        <Index Value="A-dur" />
        <Index Value="A-durs" />
        <Index Value="A dur" />
        <Index Value="A durs" />
      </Lexeme>
    </Lemma>
  </Article>
```

When I try to find the nouns using the findall or inter methods, they don't return anything.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[1])
root = tree.getroot()

for noun in root.findall('subst.'):
      print(noun.attrib)
```

I get the same empty results if I use findall() and iter()

However, when I search for 'Article' instead of 'subst.' I get get all the dictionary entries:

```
for noun in root.iter('Article'):
      print(noun.attrib)
{'ID': '1179604', 'Sortkey': 'övning'}
{'ID': '1179617', 'Sortkey': 'övningskörning'}
{'ID': '1179637', 'Sortkey': 'övre'}
{'ID': '1179644', 'Sortkey': 'övrig'}
{'ID': '1179656', 'Sortkey': 'övärld'}
```

I have tried other key words, like 'Lemma', which don't return anything. 'Idiom' returns items when I use iter() but not findall()

I am clearly missing something obvious about how these methods work.

Comment: I don't see the string 'noun' in your sample xml. Could it be called something else?

Comment: @ColeTierney noun is just the placeholder for the iterator in the for loop. Look between the quotes for the string I'm searching for, like 'Article' or 'subst.'

Comment: Oh yes I see that now. Thanks!

Comment: `root.findall('subst.')` does not return anything since there are no elements with the name `subst.`. What you do have in the XML sample is a `Lemma` element that has a `Type` attribute with the value `subst.`.

Comment: @mzjn Ah I see. I didn't realise that the search does not extend the way I need. So how do I search for articles that have Lemmas with the Type attribute value of `subst.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to search for `Article` elements with a `Lemma` child whose `Type` attribute has the value `subst.`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("dictionary.xml")

for article in tree.findall("Article"):
    lemma = article.find("Lemma")
    if lemma and lemma.get("Type") == "subst.":
        print(article.attrib)
```

Output:

```
{'ID': '1000002', 'Sortkey': 'a'}
```

---

With [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html), you can use a compact XPath expression to get the same result:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("article.xml")

for article in tree.xpath("Article[Lemma[@Type='subst.']]"):
    print(article.attrib)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an xslt transform solution. Since the xml source is large, you may enjoy added performance by letting libxml do the heavy lifting. To try it, copy the following into a file named swedish-dictionary.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Dictionary/Article/Lemma[@Type = 'subst.']">
        <xsl:text>{'ID': '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@ID" />
        <xsl:text>', 'Sortkey': '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@Sortkey" />
        <xsl:text>'}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the xml source file is named swedish-dictionary.xml, the python would look like the following:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('swedish-dictionary.xsl') as stylesheet:
    transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(stylesheet.read()))

with open('swedish-dictionary.xml') as xml:
    print(transform(etree.parse(xml)))
```

Result with the sample xml:

```
{'ID': '1000002', 'Sortkey': 'a'}
```

You could also get the same results with libxml's xsltproc utility:

```
xsltproc swedish-dictionary.xsl swedish-dictionary.xml
```